# How to create RDNS (Reverse DNS)

Tags: ubuntu, centos, reverse-dns, dns-zone, ptr-record

How to create a RDNS (Reverse DNS) in centos or Ubuntu [PTR record]

I searched a lot in Internet and didn't find any solutions. I got a idea it can be done by BIND or BIND9.

In some forum i seen some peoples wrote "RDNS cannot created by user, it can only created by Server provider or server manager" - Is it True.

I tried my best all possible way but failed, Can anyone provide me a procedure or idea to create RDNS.

Example

```
Example.com - xxx.xxx.xxx.xx0
Example.xyz - xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1
xyz.example.com - xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2
```

Thanks you.

Comment: RDNS can be created only by your ISP. That's true.

Comment: That's not quite true.  I have, for example, one network in which I own the whole block of IPs, so I am officially the PTR record holder.  You have to have an arrangement with your upstream provider.  Basically they have to be willing to "forward" your DNS server PTR records.  Although most nowadays have an external facility/API to manage this so that you don't accidentally claim IPs you're not entitled to, particularly if you share the IP block with others.

Answer (score 3):

Well... not so sure if this is the answer but basically, you only need a `PTR` record on your `domain.reverse.conf` file that would look like this:

```
5   IN  PTR    www.example.com.
```

and on `named.conf`:

```
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;   
    file "domain.reverse.conf";   
};
```

Basically, that would asign a PTR record for `192.168.0.5` to `www.example.com`

As @tudor mentioned, in a real scenario, you would need to talk firstly with your service provider, as you are not the owner of a block of IPs (in most cases) but on a local environment, it will work.